# SpritKit background image has margins

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am following a tutorial on SpriteKit and when I add my background image to the scene, the image does not fill up the entire scene (has margins).

The project is a universal project, and I am using size classes (same effect when I turn it off).

I am new to Swift and SpriteKit, so maybe I am missing something. Here is my code (from a brand new project):

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
    background.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    background.size = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)

    self.addChild(background)

}
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image]

I added the position and size code just to be sure. Also, frame.size is showing (1024, 768) but bounds.size shows the proper (640, 1136). Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find that in your ViewController.swift, the current scale mode is `.AspectFill` which is sometimes perfectly find to use but in your case, you need to change that to

`scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill`

which will make sure that the size fits perfectly into any size screen. You then use `self.view.frame.size` instead of `self.view.bounds.size` and you are good to go! Ask if you need any more information, though the documentation explains the scaleModes quite well:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/SKSceneScaleModeFill

Comment: Thanks! That worked great and I appreciate the documentation! Great answer

Comment: Not a problem, just as a side note, this whole problem arises because we now load SKScenes from a file. Inside this file you will notice that the scene size is set to (1024,768) which is an iPad screen size and so Xcode copes with this by setting the images to how they would look if placed on an iPad screen. By setting the scale mode to ResizeFill, you chop off the excess screen size and are left with the size to fit your device.